# C# - passing color in a query string

Tags: c#, query-string

I am using

```
ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(file, fileName, new Instructions(string.Format("width={0}&height={1}&format=jpg&{2}=auto", width, height, croppingType)), false, false));
```

to resize my photo in a specific settings, what I want is when the user writes the color value inside the query string to pass it inside the `new Instructions()` to specify the needed color.

Comment: Please provide more information. There's no such thing als an `ImageJob` in standard .NET, so it must be some sort of third party library - which one?

Comment: Also important to state what web framework you're using. is this ASP.NET? WebForms? MVC? Which version? Does this code run inside a controller? A Page's CodeBehind class?

Comment: this is an imageResizer nuget, using it inside a handler

Comment: Link? Which one? Docs? Anything?

Comment: http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4

Comment: Right. Now on to the next question: What's the needed color? How is it relevant for resizing? Where is that feature documented in the docs you linked?

Comment: I don't really know, in the definition of new Instructions() i saw "background color" field but I don't know how to use it, though i want to pass it as a hexadecimal value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the full command reference](http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/reference):

> bgcolor=color name | hex code (6-char). Sets the background/whitespace color.

e.g.: `bgcolor=ffffff` sets the background to white.